# Unable to click ViewSeats button in redbus site using selenium

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, selenium, xpath

I was trying to automate a flow using redbus site. I was not able to click View Seats button in the second page after selecting journey details in the first page of RedBus site. I have tried clicking using javascript click() as well.

Please find the code below:

```
WebDriver ffdri = new FirefoxDriver();
    ffdri.get("https://www.redbus.in/Booking/SelectBus.aspx? fromCityId=123&toCityId=122&doj=10-Oct-2015&busType=Any&opId=0");

    ffdri.manage().window().maximize();


    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(ffdri,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Travels")));

    JavascriptExecutor js =  (JavascriptExecutor) ffdri;
    js.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('dpBtn')[1].click();");

    ffdri.findElement(By.id("BusType_AC")).click();

    ffdri.findElement(By.id("BusType_Sleeper")).click();
    js.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('dpBtn')[1].click();");

    ffdri.findElement(By.linkText("Fare")).click();

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@class='viewSeatsBtn']"))).click();

//      System.out.println(val.getText());

//js.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('viewSeatsBtn')[0].click();");
//      WebElement ViewSeats =     ffdri.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='viewSeatsBtn']"));
//js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ViewSeats);
```

Comment: what exception are you getting and at what line?

Comment: I did not get any exception.. In UI nothing is happening and the button is not getting clicked..